# How to isolate CSS divs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I need to display an extracted html content ( HTML ONLY , no JS ) in a collapse/expand div but the extracted content is not 'valid' all the time and it may have more closing divs than it should, thus it closes the divs of my UI and  breaks the UI. 
Is there any solution to this issue except iframes ? perhaps a js library to sanitize this kind of content.  I'm using AngularJS and boostrap. 
I think it could also be done using Shadow DOM but I'm not sure how it works/can be done so I'm wondering if there is any expand/collapse plugin that uses shadow dom.

Comment: fix the source is the best solution, anything after that is a hack

Answer (score 0):

You could create create an off-page div, add your (possibly invalid) HTML content there, let the HTML parser take care of everything and then take the `innerHTML` of the element again and put in your page:

```
var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
div.innerHTML = '<div></div><span>h</span></div>'; // whatever your content

console.log( div.innerHTML );
// will output "<div></div><span>h</span>" for the example
```

Comment: @Brunis The included content has no JS, but OP references as JS lib to sanitize the content in the question.

Comment: my apologies, the true nature of his request had eluded my eyes :(